# Change if condition dynamically

Tags: php, if-statement, dynamic

I'd like to dynamically change a condition, depending on whether or not a table is empty.

If the table is empty, it should record all data up to yesterday, if not empty, it should record today's data.

My current code is not working:

```
$db->get('history');
$emptyTable = $db->count; // This return 0 or 1
$condition = setCondition($emptyTable);

foreach($extract as $trade) {
  $date = strtotime($trade['Date']);
  $today = strtotime(date("d/m/Y"));

  if($condition) {
    // do something
  }
}

function setCondition($bool) {
  switch ($bool) {
    case 1:
      return $date == $today;
      break;
    case 0:
      return $date < $today;
      break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not passing `$date` and `$today` to your function and call it inside `foreach` and enclose the return part in setCondition so that it will return the string ..

```
 foreach($extract as $trade) {
      $date = strtotime($trade['Date']);
      $today = strtotime(date("d/m/Y"));
      $condition = setCondition($emptyTable,$today,$date);
   // echo $condition//condition string
      if($condition) {
        // do something
      }
    }


function setCondition($bool,$today,$date) {
  switch ($bool) {
    case 1:
      return "'$date' == '$today'";
      break;
    case 0:
      return "'$date' < '$today'";
      break;
  }
}
```

[DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e5684d26a1d54fdda691d97208c9b0a38ba4c95c)

Answer (score 0):

Your condition itself needs to be a call to a function returning a boolean value. This is what your `setCondition` function does:

```
function setCondition($bool) {
  switch ($bool) {
    case 1:
      return $date == $today;
      break;
    case 0:
      return $date < $today;
      break;
  }
}
```

Since it does not set anything, I suggest you rename it `evaluateCondition`.

Henceforth, you can directly call this function as a condition:

```
if(evaluateCondition($booleanVariableToTest)) {
    // do something
}
```

Regarding why your code does not work: you basically evaluate `$condition` once, at the beginning:

```
$condition = setCondition($emptyTable);
```

After that, `$condition` never changes. Therefore, it is not dynamically re-evaluated.

---

**Edit**

From reading a comment of you, I understand that you're not actually trying to dynamically evaluate a condition, but *statically* evaluate it, depending on other parameters (namely, `$date` and `$today`).

Your function needs to take these variables as arguments, so their names actually mean something in the scope of this function. The right code is:

```
function setCondition($bool, $date, $today) {
  switch ($bool) {
    case 1:
      return $date == $today;
      break;
    case 0:
      return $date < $today;
      break;
  }
}
```

In this case, you do not need to call the `setCondition` function at every iteration, so your `if` test remains:

```
if($condition) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: That's the thing, I'm not evaluating condition, just I'm trying to pass "$date == $today" or "$date < $today" to $condition and trying to build dinamically  if($date == $today) or if($date < $today)

Comment: @CarlosDiaz I indeed understood what you're willing to do, and updated my answer.